# Do we have reversed recursive feature elimination (RFE)?

Tags: feature-selection

We usually use RFE to eliminate less-important features to improve model performance.
I wonder if we have a reversed RFE, which intentionally remove important features?
The intention for this is to test how well can less-important features predict.